# Parse XML in jQuery by passing an id

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

I have 4 blocks of xml, that I want to parse whith jQuery making one ajax call. Now four blocks of xml are different from each other(But the structure is same). I am trying to parse this xml by passing an id to each of the xml block, But in my ajax call I am not able to retreive the id attribute as it is the first thing that I need to capture to pass to the ajax function.

I tried something like this:

XML is here:

```
       <dropdown>
            <test id="1">
            <optionheading>
                <heads>Heading 1</heads>
                            <value>
                                    <values images='images/1.gif'>Option1</values>
                                    <values images='images/2.gif'>Option2</values>
                                    <values images='images/3.gif'>Option3</values>
                            </value>
            </optionheading>
    .....................................

    ............................
    </test>
    <test id='2">
    <optionheading>
                <heads id="b">H..................
    ..................
    ............
    </test>
</dropdown>
```

I need to get id of test1, test2, et-al

Ajax is Here:

```
$("document").ready(function() {
                $.ajax({ 
                    type: "GET",
                    url:"dropdown.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success :function(xml) {
                        var select = $("#mySelect"); 
                        //I am getting id here
                        var id=$(xml).find('test').attr('id'); 

                        $(xml).find('test'+id).each(function() {
                            $(this).find('optionheading').each(function() {
                            var opthead = $(this).fin......................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you well, the following should happen (output boldfaced):

- `<test id="IDHERE">` should populate **`<select ID="IDHERE">`**
- `<optionheading>` should create an **`<optgroup>`**  with a **label** as defined at `<heads>`
- Each `<optgroup>` is populated with **`<option>`** elements, according to the given `<values>` elements

The code below is the jQuery method to implement this idea, as requested.

Note: `$('test', xml)` is a shorthand for `$(xml).find('test')`.
Note2: Since an ID must be unique, `select#yourID` is equal to `#yourID`.
Note3: The `<values>` tag at the XML is not necessary for this script.

```js
success: function(xml){
    //Loop through each `<test>`
    $('test', xml).each(function(test_index){
        var id = $(this).attr('id'); //Get the ID of the `<test>`
        // Select <select> element with ID `ID` using the `select#ID` selector
        var select = $('select#' + id);
        $('optionheading', this).each(function() {
            $('values', this).each(function(){
                var $values = $(this);
                $('<option>')
                    .val($values.attr('images'))
                    .text($values.text())
                    .appendTo(optgroup);
            });
            $('<optgroup>')
                .attr('label', $('heads', this).text())
                .appendTo(select);
        });
    });
}
```

Possible HTML after executing:

```
<select id='1'>
    <optgroup label='Heading 1'>
        <option value='images/1.gif'>Option1</option>
        <option value='images/2.gif'>Option2</option>
        <option value='images/3.gif'>Option3</option>
    <optgroup>
    ....
</select>
<select id="2">
    ...
```

Comment: Actuallly I just need to process the first block of test. Let me explain I am pulling the options in test block to a dropdown and another test block to another dropdown and so on. These dropdowns are dependent on each other

Comment: Hey Rob,Actually I am looking for code reusability/portability. I dont want to change my javacript everytime I add something. Rather I would like to just update my xml and let jquery take care of it. like how i have done in my script by passing an id

Comment: @Mike So, what **exactely** do you want? Do you want to walk through **all** `<test>` elements, and process the `<optionheading>` tag?

Comment: I want to process the dropdown, take one block of test at a time and put these in a select dropdown(heads as optgroup and value as options).Each select dropdown has somewhere around 15 options and 5 optgroup. Next dropdown has another 15 options(heads as optgroup and values as options options). Since My dropdowns are dependent on other factor, so at a time I want to load only one dropdown(i-e one test block). If I need another dropdown then I hide the first dropdown and show the next dropdown whose options come from test2 block of xml. I hope I am clear.... and ya thanks for your help

Comment: @Mike So, you're populating each `<select>` after the AJAX call? Currently, your intentinded behaviour looks like "Process the first `<test>` element, and ignore the others".

Comment: Exactly, My html just has <select id="mySelect">
    <option>Loading the options</option>
   </select> 

The options of dropdown are coming from xml. I am able to process the whole xml, but not it in the block wise, so that I could put those options in the relevant dropdowns, what I thought would be  good idea is to have each xml test block an id and pass that to ajax call and process the script.

Comment: @Mike Can you post a fiddle in the comments with your current code, and explain your wishes more clear? You haven't defined the ID-format of your `<select>` elements. I'll check back after dinner.

Comment: Let me explain further. My html should have 4 select dropdowns, they have same structure but no. of options for each may differ. At any time on my html page I am just showing one dropdown and hiding the other three, depending on the criteria, I am pulling the options from the xml. Now when my dropdown changes I need to load different select dropdown and changes the options accordingly, they need to come from xml with test block 2 and so on...

Comment: @Mike AJAX `Test 1, Test2, Test 3, Test4` --> ????? -> Populate `<select>`. What's `?????`? What's the logic behind it? Should the `<select id="youhaventtoldme-3">` be populated with data from `<test id="3">`? Also, how do your `<test>` elements appear? `id=1 2 3 4` or `id=1 3 4 2` (random)?

Comment: I am getting confused here Rob, id can be anything, I just give it 1 2 ----- so that my attr for test will become test1, test2 et-al.. 
Bottom line is that I need to process only one block of xml which has an id attribute. I  am done almost but I am not able to get this id for my ajax script, as it needs to be first line for ajax function to proceed.

Comment: Though I am marking this as accepted answer, but <select ID="IDHERE"> is not what I populate from xml. I have in my html select tag
<select id="mySelect">
    <option>Loading</option>
   </select>, but optgroup and values are coming from xml.